# LINQ to Objects - any performance benefit in using ToArray / ToList over IEnumerable<string>

Tags: linq, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

This is almost undoubtedly a dumb question.  In my defence I'm ill.  Anyway.

I've got an in memory list of objects.  I've used the following expression to pull out the strings I'm interested in from my list of objects:

```
var myStrings = myListOfObjects.Select(r => r.MyString);
```

This provides me with an IEnumerable of string.  myStrings will be reused a number of different times in my code later.  What I'm wondering is, is there any performance benefit at all in performing a ToArray or ToList (ie a "greedy" operator) on this prior to making use of it?  (So my operations would be directly against an Array / List.)

For what it's worth myStrings will be re-used in it's entirety when it is used.

Comment: Thanks guys - would have accepted sooner but I got iller before I got better :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a speed-space tradeoff.

If your `Select()` callback is computationally expensive, you probably want to computer it once and store it for later.

If not, you probably want to save on storage and compute it every time.

If you need random access, you should definitely call `ToList()`, because `ElementAt()` is O(n).

Note that `ToList()` is faster than `ToArray()`, because `ToArray()` needs to trim the array after it finishes.

Comment: Very interesting to learn that ToList is faster than ToArray; I'd always assumed that it would be the other way around (without having any particular reason).  I'm now wondering if Arrays are faster / slower to process than Lists.  Is there a good source for this sort of information or is this just based on your own experiments?

Comment: @JohnnyReilly: If you read the source, you'll see that `ToArray()` has more steps.  (Since arrays cannot have extra space, there is no way around that).  I suspect that arrays are a tiny bit faster than lists, but probably not enough to justify a copy.

Answer (score 1):

`myStrings` is just a query and not a collection. If you need it multiple times and it's not too large (for memory) you should better create a collection via `ToArray` or `ToList`.

Otherwise you're executing the query every time you access it(f.e. via `foreach`) due to it's [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). This can also cause nasty bugs   if the query now returns a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it an IEnumerable would be the best unless you specifically **need** the List or Array functionality.  No casting == fewer compute cycles.

Comment: This has nothing to do with casting.

Comment: Ahh.  The Linq query returns an IQueryable doesn't it.  My mistake.

Comment: No; it returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: And the OP is asking if there would be any benefit to returning at List or array instead of IEnumerable<T> correct?

Comment: Yes, but that still has nothing to do with casting.